# How to pull Message header details in KafkaListener method if message is a GenericRecord

Tags: spring-kafka

I want to be able to get the record.Key from the message of type avro schema.

I have my kafkaConsumerConfig class which sets the properties and contains the kafkalistener contrainerfactory

```
    public ConsumerFactory<String, GenericRecord> kafkaConsumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, serverList);
        properties.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
        properties.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "SCRAM-SHA-256");
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer.class);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);  
        ...;
        
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(properties);
    }
    
    //Used to poll for messages
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericRecord> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() 
    { 
        
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericRecord> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
      factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory());
      return factory;
    }
```

This is my listener class:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topicName", groupId = "groupIDName")
public class KafkaListenerclass {
    
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaListenerclass.class);
    
    @KafkaHandler
      void listenerGenericRecord(GenericRecord record) {
        logger.info("KafkaHandler[Default] {}", record);
        System.out.println("Im here generic listener..."+ record.toString());
      }
    
    @KafkaHandler
    public void listenPayload(@Payload String message,@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String messageKey) {
         System.out.println("Im here listenPayload..."+ messageKey);
    }
```

It always uses the listenerGEnericRecord() which I cant seem to pull the other message details from.
When I remove this method to see if it falls to using the listenPayload()  I get :

Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: No method found for class org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record

I cant seem to find any help around this, except to rewrite the code which doesnt use this bean structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about like this:

```
void listenerGenericRecord(GenericRecord record,
           @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String messageKey) {
```

The `GenericRecord` is a POJO for Avro data which is stored only in the Kafka record `body`. The headers of the `ConsumerRecord` are fully not related to Avro. So, if there are some metadata stored in Kafka record headers, you should distinguish them from the data stored only in the body.

Comment: This works perfectly thankyou.  Thanks for the nice explanation also